# How to generate images in discord bot through slash commands in pycord?

Tags: python, discord, pycord

I am facing problem in copying the prompt from the slash command

```
@bot.slash_command(name = 'generate', description='Generate any image')
async def generate(message, imageprompt: Option(str, description="The prompt to generate", required = True)):
    await message.channel.trigger_typing() #shows that the bot is typing 
    prompt = message.summary(imageprompt)
    image_url = await generate_image(prompt)
    try:
        await message.respond(image_url) #responds to the slash command (bot must respond within 3 seconds)
    except:
        await message.send(image_url) #sends as a regular message, if it cannot send as a slash command
```

here in the 4th line how do i make the bot capable of copying the text from imageprompt and generate the image according to that?
I have the generate image coded previously but i cant figure it out in case of slash commands of how to generate the image according to the user provided context

I tried using other syntax like message.content,message.summary
none of them work
i tried googling but found no answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument given to the slash command is a discord.ApplicationContext object. This is context so thats why its commonly named `ctx`.

The line `await ctx.defer()` makes the bot do the "bot is thinking" loading so you can still respond if the image took a while to generate.

`prompt` is the value given by the users and is asked for when you run the slash command"

And finally to respond to the message i use `ctx.respond`

```
@bot.slash_command(name="generate", description="Generate any image")
async def generate(
    ctx: discord.ApplicationContext,
    prompt: Option(str, description="The prompt to generate", required=True),
):
    await ctx.defer()
    image_url = await generate_image(prompt)
    await ctx.respond(image_url)
```

This code should work provided that the `generate_image` function you made works.